# How do I set the style of UIToolbar programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I can do this in xib file by selecting one of the option in the "Style" drop down menu eg. "Black Translucent". How can I do it programmatically ?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view controller where you want to set this, add the following to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `UIToolbar.barStyle` and `UIToolbar.translucent`.